# Indexer mode Unknown

Tags: magento-enterprise, ee-1.13, index, indexer, shell

I am running Magento EE 1.13.1.0
I set all the index options in System=>Configuration=>Advanced=>Index Management to "Update when scheduled".

When I run

```
$ php -f indexer.php mode
Product Flat Data:                  unknown
Stock Status:                       unknown
Catalog product price:              unknown
Category URL Rewrites:              unknown
Product URL Rewrites:               unknown
URL Redirects:                      unknown
Catalog Category/Product Index:     unknown
Catalog Search Index:               unknown
Tag Aggregation Data:               Manual Update
Product Attributes:                 Manual Update
```

**What is the meaning of the "unknown" mode** and how can I repair?

Answer (score 2):

**Unknown** is the default status hardcoded in the `indexer.php` shell script:

```
        foreach ($processes as $process) {
            /* @var $process Mage_Index_Model_Process */
            $status = 'unknown';
            if ($this->getArg('status')) {
                switch ($process->getStatus()) {
                    case Mage_Index_Model_Process::STATUS_PENDING:
                        $status = 'Pending';
                        break;
                    case Mage_Index_Model_Process::STATUS_REQUIRE_REINDEX:
                        $status = 'Require Reindex';
                        break;
                    case Mage_Index_Model_Process::STATUS_RUNNING:
                        $status = 'Running';
                        break;
                    default:
                        $status = 'Ready';
                        break;
                }
            } else {
                switch ($process->getMode()) {
                    case Mage_Index_Model_Process::MODE_SCHEDULE:
                        $status = 'Update by schedule';
                        break;
                    case Mage_Index_Model_Process::MODE_REAL_TIME:
                        $status = 'Update on Save';
                        break;
                    case Mage_Index_Model_Process::MODE_MANUAL:
                        $status = 'Manual Update';
                        break;
                }
            }
            echo sprintf('%-35s ', $process->getIndexer()->getName() . ':') . $status ."\n";

        }
```

As you can see from the code this default status is displayed when the indexer mode is not one of the following:

- `Mage_Index_Model_Process::MODE_SCHEDULE`
- `Mage_Index_Model_Process::MODE_REAL_TIME`
- `Mage_Index_Model_Process::MODE_MANUAL`

However, **Magento does not define any other mode out of the box so in theory, you should never get unknown mode.**

What you can do to debug it:

Add a default case to display what mode your index is on to find out what's going on:

Replace the following code:

```
            switch ($process->getMode()) {
                case Mage_Index_Model_Process::MODE_SCHEDULE:
                    $status = 'Update by schedule';
                    break;
                case Mage_Index_Model_Process::MODE_REAL_TIME:
                    $status = 'Update on Save';
                    break;
                case Mage_Index_Model_Process::MODE_MANUAL:
                    $status = 'Manual Update';
                    break;
            }
```

With:

```
            switch ($process->getMode()) {
                case Mage_Index_Model_Process::MODE_SCHEDULE:
                    $status = 'Update by schedule';
                    break;
                case Mage_Index_Model_Process::MODE_REAL_TIME:
                    $status = 'Update on Save';
                    break;
                case Mage_Index_Model_Process::MODE_MANUAL:
                    $status = 'Manual Update';
                    break;
                default:
                    $status = $process->getMode();
                    break;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is normal behaviour of Magento EE so there is nothing to repair.
I observe the exact same output in an installation of Magento EE v. 1.14.2.3.

Indexers are printed by iterating over `$processes` in indexer.php. It is a collection of type `Enterprise_Index_Model_Resource_Process_Collection`. Have a look into this class: in method `initializeSelect` this collection is built by unioning `$oldIndexersSelect` and `$newIndexersSelect`. For `$newIndexersSelect` several fields are set to empty constants:

```
                ...
                'started_at' => new Zend_Db_Expr('NULL'),
                'ended_at' => new Zend_Db_Expr('NULL'),
                'mode' => new Zend_Db_Expr('NULL'),
                'events' => new Zend_Db_Expr('0'),
                ...
```

So this is why `indexer.php` displays mode "unknown" and why in Index Management the column "mode" is emtpy for the same indexers.
I assume this is normal behaviour which results from Magento EE having several different indexer implementations which got integrated over the years.